# Returning Substrings Of A String In Descending Order

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice

So, I have written code to slice a string:

```
word = "Fred"

n = len(word)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n+1):
        print(word[i:j])
```

Which returns:

```
F
Fr
Fre
Fred
r
re
red
e
ed
d
```

However, I need it to return the string like this:

```
Fred
Fre
red
Fr
re
ed
F
r
e
d
```

What I have tried: I have thought about saving the slices to a list and then sorting them that way, however, that will only sort them alphabetically and that won't work. I'm pretty sure I can tweak the logic somehow to make it work.I have watched as many videos on the subject as I can to no avail. Searched Google. Asked for help in a Python Discord server. And reached out to class mates. I have also sought help on my schools tutoring site. No progress. That is why I have asked here.

How can I make this happen? I need it to return that way regardless of which string I input. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to reverse the roles of i and j.

```
word = "Fred"

n = len(word)
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(n-i+1):
        print(word[j:j + i])
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)